# template class constructor error using gcc 11.2.0

Tags: templates, gcc, construct

```
template <class T>
class UserdataValue : public Userdata {
 private:
  UserdataValue<T>(UserdataValue<T> const&);
  UserdataValue<T> operator=(UserdataValue<T> const&);
};
```

when using gcc11.2.0 comiple, error reported:
[enter image description here][1]

/home/user00/hxnextSvr2/dep/luabridge/detail/Userdata.h:247:36: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
247 |   UserdataValue(UserdataValue const&);
|                   ~                ^~~~~~
|                                    )
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhFbC.png

Comment: template <class T>
class UserdataValue : public Userdata {
 private:
  UserdataValue(const UserdataValue<T>&);
  UserdataValue<T> operator=(UserdataValue<T> const&);}

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the teplate parameter on the copy *constructor*

thus:

```
template <class T>
class UserdataValue : public Userdata {
 private:
  UserdataValue(UserdataValue<T> const&); // no template specification here
  UserdataValue<T> operator=(UserdataValue<T> const&);
};
```